# Prime divisors of $x^{16}+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

$x \in  Z$. Prove, that all prime divisors of $x^{16}+1$, which are not equal to 2, are equal $1 \pmod{32}$.

Comment: I upvoted to reverse anonymous downvote.  I am uncomfortable with immediate (i.e. $<$ 7 minutes) downvote for new user as opposed to leaving a comment such as "what is your background, what have you tried?" and giving them a chance to respond.  New users have a negative emotional reaction to downvotes.

Comment: What have you tried? It is helpful to give a bit more  context.

Comment: Proof is the same as in the case $x=2$ in the dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, downvotes have a negative impact. Next time, show your thinking, show that at least you tried and people will happily help. Here is a proper solution:

Suppose $p|x^{16}+1$. Then $x^{16}\equiv-1\pmod{p}$, leding to $x^{32}\equiv1\pmod{p}$, if we square.

Denote with $ord_x(p)$ the order of $2 \pmod{p}$. It is known that $ord_x(p)|k$ if $x^k\equiv1\pmod{p}$

Thus, $ord_x(p)|32$, so let $ord_x(p)=2^a$, $1\leq a\leq 5$. If $a<5$, then $ord_x(p)|16$ which would imply that $x^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, contradiction.

So $ord_x(p)=32$. As I said before, $ord_x(p)|k$ if $x^k\equiv1\pmod{p}$. From Fermat's little theorem, because $x^{\phi(p)}=x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ (note that $gcd(p;n)=1$) we have $32|p-1$, so $p\equiv 1\pmod{32}$.

Comment: Better to use the Order Test - see the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $x^{16}+1 \equiv 0 \bmod p$, then $x$ has multiplicative order $32$ mod $p$.